# Ionic custom back URL

Tags: ionic-framework, navigation

I have 2 - 3 pages that are a child section within a page, similar to tabs. Logically the user would not expect to go back to the previous tab on the back click. As these are implemented as separate pages the user is taken back to the individual tabs and not to the main section.

How can I get the user back to a custom URL only for some pages?

Answer (score 1):

When you go to a new tab, you could delete the previous one from history with :

```
$ionicHistory.removeBackView();
```

[Docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to custom your back function in devices i recommend this:

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function,priority)
```

In that function you can use $state.go to redirect where ever you want.

Docs [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/)

Answer (score 0):

You can skip back navigation history by using ui-view instead of ion-nav-view component.

So if for example you were using:

```
<ion-tabs> 
    <ion-tab ui-href="state">
        <ion-nav-view name="content"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

You would turn it into:

```
<a ui-sref="state">Link</a>
<div>
   <ui-view name="content"><ui-view>
</div>
```

It will require some more template layout changes but this should get you started. Basically if you use ion-nav-view you'll get history and ionic.view events, if ui-router only then just view changes.